# Inverse Distance Weighted interpolation in a grid(Python)

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

My problem set up is the following: 
I have a gird made of cells,every cells have the same dimensions.
Only 4 cells are labeled(contain a measure) and are indicated in the image by some points.
In my python program i have a dataframe, in which each row represent a grid cell.Each cell has its coordinated and a label(that is None for all the cells excluding the 4 cells that contain a measure).

[image]

[image]

What i want to do is the following: Use the inverse weighted interpolation in order to obtain a measure(label) for each unlabeled cell in my grid.
Do you have any suggestion on how to face this problem, or you know if there similar examples of code that do the same thing. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You want to compute a value at all those cells given only those 4 measurements? I must be missing something...

Comment: Yes i know but right now i have only those four measures,maybe i will be able to get more measures, what is more important is how to face the problem in general, having a grid with labeled and unlabeled cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to solve it.
First i calculated the distance between each labeled cell and each unlabeled cell, using this function

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
"""
Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
"""
# convert decimal degrees to radians 
lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
# haversine formula 
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
# Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
km = 6371* c
return km
```

Then i created a function called iwd that apply the inverse weighted distance interpolation using the standard formula.
After that i was able to obtain a a label for each cell that result in the following image:

[image]